# After updating to unity 2021.1.13.f1 isNetworkError and isHttpError is already obselete

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
```

Does anyone know how to replace this code properly to the updated one

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Unity `2020.2` you now use [`UnityWebRequest.result`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-result.html)

Example from [`UnityWebRequest.Get`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html)

> ```c#
> using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
> {
>     // Request and wait for the desired page.
>     yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
>
>     string[] pages = uri.Split('/');
>     int page = pages.Length - 1;
>
>     switch (webRequest.result)
>     {
>         case UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError:
>         case UnityWebRequest.Result.DataProcessingError:
>             Debug.LogError(pages[page] + ": Error: " + webRequest.error);
>             break;
>         case UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError:
>             Debug.LogError(pages[page] + ": HTTP Error: " + webRequest.error);
>             break;
>         case UnityWebRequest.Result.Success:
>             Debug.Log(pages[page] + ":\nReceived: " + webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
>             break;
>     }
> }
> ```

Or the simplier example from [`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html)

> ```c#
> WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
> form.AddField("myField", "myData");
>
> using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://www.my-server.com/myform", form))
> {
>     yield return www.SendWebRequest();
>
>     if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
>     {
>         Debug.Log(www.error);
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I solve mine like that!

instead using: if(www.isNetworkError)

I wrote: if(www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError)

Full example is below:

```
 IEnumerator Get(string url)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        
        if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError)
        {
            Debug.LogError(www.error);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "www.isHttpError" with "(www.result== UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)" and  "www.isNetworkError" with "(www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError)".

Assuming www means the request object.